# How to enable Basic authentication to WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.21

Tags: authentication

I am trying to make a basic authentication to webSphere application server v8.5.5.21. I configured my deployment descriptor correctly, did all the actions listed in IBM Infocenter related to "enabling user authentication using file-based registry only", mapped my users to appropriate roles, clicked OK, tested and it worked. But when I moved on to something else in the administrative console, I realised that there are no "OK", "Save" or "Apply" buttons in "Security role to user/group mapping", thus all my changes can take action only while I stay on that page, and as soon as I click a link in the console all the changes are instantly reset. I think it might be a bug in the console. Is there a solution to it? Perhaps a way to directly edit an xml file with these properties?

How to save the mapped user in admin console of websphere application server V8.5.5.21. I am unable to get **save** option after adding map user. How to get it.